# Why doesn't ice:commandButton accept onmouseover/onmouseout when it's disabled?

Tags: icefaces-1.8

I'm working with ICEFaces components and I have the need of setting a tooltip on an `ice:commandButton`.

The button can be enabled or not according to particular conditions, but my problems is that when the button is disabled the tooltip is not displayed.

I display the tooltip by calling a Javascript method in the `onmouseover` attribute and close it via `onmouseout`.

Checking with IE dev tools, the two attributes don't get rendered when the button is disabled.

How could I modify this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled components neither get focus nor react on any events.

[HTML Reference:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533732.aspx)

> When an element is disabled, it
>   appears dimmed and does not respond to
>   user input. Disabled elements do not
>   respond to mouse events, nor will they
>   respond to the contentEditable
>   property.

As a workaround you can assign the tooltip to a `<div/>` around the commandButton.